# Label not defined Error

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i have this code i'm using a goto option
i'm always getting that the label nextrecord is not defined .. what shall i do ? am i missing something? can you please tell me when shall i do :) thank you in advance !
that's the code i'm writing ..

```
Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    Try
        Timer.Interval = 5000
        sendSched()
        If send = True Then
            GoTo NEXTRECORD
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub 

Private Sub sendSched()
    subTable.Rows.Clear()
    subTable = selectSubscriber(content.mt, content.clID)
    subCount = subTable.Rows.Count()
    If content.timeSend = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm") Then
        Timer.Enabled = False
        UpdateListBoxRec2("Sending content: " & content.contentSend & " to :")
        For Each subRow As DataRow In subTable.Rows
            content.moSend = subRow("sim_mo")
            UpdateListBoxRec2(content.moSend)
            MsgBox(content.contentSend)
        Next
        send = True
    Else
        Timer.Enabled = True
        Timer.Interval = 5000
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub start_check_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles start_check.CheckedChanged
  For Each contentRow As DataRow In contentTable.Rows
            content.mt = contentRow("cnt_mt")
            content.clID = contentRow("cnt_cl_id")
            content.contentSend = contentRow("cnt_content")
            content.id = contentRow("cnt_id")
            content.timeSend = contentRow("cnt_time_to_send")
            UpdateListBoxRec("Content to send at: " & content.timeSend)
            Timer.Enabled = True
            Timer.Interval = 0
NEXTRECORD:
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: At first glance it looks like the control flow is very broken here.  When the condition is true, you want the control to flow to a `Next` statement, even though a loop was never started?  All things considered, I imagine the best solution here would be to not use `GoTo` at all.

Comment: the for loop was started ! each part is in a different function

Comment: Not according to the code posted in the question.  We can only help with code you show us, not code you keep somewhere else.

Comment: okey i updated my code ... can you help me now :) ?

Comment: Why are you using GOTO at all?

Comment: because when the timer is stopped it's not returning to the for loop to continue the next rows..

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury: Now the control flow is even _more_ broken.  And you're still trying to send control to a `Next` statement when no loop has started.  Honestly, you shouldn't even be using `GoTo` here.  (Or anywhere, really.)  It's not even clear from this code what you're *trying* to do, let alone how it should be done.

Comment: @david my problem is that let's say i have 3 records to read in the for loop when i read the first one the timer starts do the work and then it's stopped and it's not returning to the for loop to continue reading the next two records... so that's why i tried to use a goto can suggest something else to fix my prob?

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury: The timer should be running in a completely separate thread which doesn't interrupt the loop.  If the code needs to run synchronously then instead of a timer just call a function.  What is the actual logic that needs to be achieved here?  Not what have you done to try to fix ongoing problems, but what does this code actually do?

Comment: @david i have a field for time in my table and everytime this field is equal to system date i need to popup a message so i'm reading my records row by row get the time keep comparing it with the system date until it's equal, popup the message and then read the next row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am i missing something?

I think so.  A) You cannot GOTO a point in a different procedure and B) its a bad idea to GOTO a location inside another loop (if it is even legal).  C) It also *appears* that you are using a timer as a loop control means and D) the location of the NEXTRECORD label seems to indicate you are trying to GOTO/CALL/jump into a loop inside an event procedure.

Change sendSched() to a function with returns True/False depending on whether to send or not (very similar to Douglas' answer).

Then gut start_check_CheckedChanged to a new procedure with that code in it, such as:

```
Private Sub AddContent
   For Each contentRow As DataRow In contentTable.Rows
    ...
    ...
   Next
End Sub
```

Now, you can call it from the event procedure AND/OR call it from the Timer_Tick event as needed and eliminate the GOTO and the **send** global/module flag variable.

It *looks like* you might have been trying to use GOTO to avoid re-processing things in `start_check_CheckedChanged` (even though something is being cleared every time it is processed with `subTables.Rows.Clear`).  First though, you are iterating all the rows in the event when you might be able to examine the event args (`sender` and `e`) to know precisely which thing to process (provided it is a legitimate event and not something you are firing in code.)

You might also be to examine .timesend to determine if that packet (or whatever they are) has been sent.  Something like:

```
For Each contentRow As DataRow In contentTable.Rows
    If content.timesend <> String.Empty Then   ' or <> DateTime.Now.MinValue.ToString
    ...
    ' process or send it
    ...
    End If
Next
```

Alternatively, since it looks like `content` is something you devised, you could add a `Sent` flag you set after sending each item, and use `If content.Sent = False Then...` to skip over the ones already sent.

HTH

Comment: you are not getting to the point !! the problem is that when the timer finishes the job and exit from the sub it's not returning to the for loop to continue to the next row even if i do the test on timesend

Comment: The bigger points are in ABCD: you CANNOT do many of the things you are trying to do.  A legitimate use of a Timer is to start a task, not continue a loop in some other procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This should be totally rewritten.  It isn't quite clear what you are trying to do here, but try this:

```
If Not send  Then
  For Each contentRow As DataRow In contentTable.Rows
            content.mt = contentRow("cnt_mt")
            content.clID = contentRow("cnt_cl_id")
            content.contentSend = contentRow("cnt_content")
            content.id = contentRow("cnt_id")
            content.timeSend = contentRow("cnt_time_to_send")
            UpdateListBoxRec("Content to send at: " & content.timeSend)
            Timer.Enabled = True
            Timer.Interval = 0
   Next
End If
```